# Is there an HTML attribute dedicated to setting the base URL for all descendants of an element?

Tags: html, attributes, base-url

HTML provides the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element as a means of specifying the base URL for all relative links in a document:

```css
div,ol {margin:0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/">
    <base target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Web Development Tags at StackOverflow.com :</div>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="css">css</li>
      <li><a href="javascript">javascript</li>
      <li><a href="html">html</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, as is, it only allows one base URL per document.

Given the hierarchical nature of HTML, I was hoping I could find an HTML attribute dedicated to setting the base URL for all descendants of an element. I cannot find this.

If no attribute like this exists, I would imagine that it was already proposed a long time ago, and I'm interested in why it was rejected. This too, I have not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594852/is-there-an-html-attribute-dedicated-to-setting-the-base-url-for-all-descendants#comment123325200_69594852) by [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci):

> It was indeed proposed a long time ago. [At least once, in May 2007](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007May/1225.html). And the xml:base attribute dates back at least as far as [1999](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xmlbase-19991220). - Alohci, Oct 29, 2021 at 13:02

Answer (score -1):

Well as i know, and stated in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

- The  tag specifies the base URL and/or target for all relative URLs in a document.
- The  tag must have either an href or a target attribute present, or both.
- There can only be one single  element in a document, and it must be inside the `<head>` element.

But as you mentioned this tag needs an upgrade. Maybe a numeric id can define other sources for specific relative URL's. I agree with you on this.

Comment: You're only repeating what he already knows about that tag and agreeing with what he wants. This doesn't answer the question.